# Composite keys laravel schema builder

Tags: php, laravel

I need two composite primary keys and only one should be `AUTO INCREMENT` what I tried so far:

```
// first try 
Schema::create("kitchen", function($table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('restaurant_id');
                $table->primary(array('id', 'restaurant_id'));
                $table->string('name');
            });
// second try
 Schema::create("kitchen", function($table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('restaurant_id');
                $table->primary('restaurant_id');
                $table->string('name');
            });
```

None works. Error message:

`[Exception]

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary ke

  y defined (SQL: alter table`kitchen`add primary key kitchen_restaurant_id

  _primary(`restaurant_id`)) (Bindings: array (

  ))`

The solution without `Schema` builder: first, I need to add two composite primary keys and then I need to make one of the `AUTO INCREMENT` but I think `Schema` builder can't do this.

**Note:** I can do this with **SQL**, I mean no problem with MySQL

Any suggestions?

**Summary:**

What I need is;

http://oi39.tinypic.com/es91ft.jpg

with `Schema` builder

Answer (score 22):

You can do this with a little help from the unprepared method:

```
Schema::create("kitchen", function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('restaurant_id');
    $table->string('name');
});

DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE `kitchen` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ,  `restaurant_id` )');
```

This is tested, and works!

I know it's a little late, and you might have moved on, but someone else might come across this :)

Comment: Nice solution it helped me thanks saving my day

Answer (score 11):

It makes no sense to have the autoincrement as part of a composite primary key as it will be unique for every record anyway.
If you want an autoincrement primary key and a unique composite key on eg 2 other columns such as 'restaurant_id' and 'name':

```
Schema::create("kitchen", function($table) 
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('restaurant_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unique(['restaurant_id', 'name']);
});
```

Comment: i believe this is the correct answer, as in most scenarios in eloquent relation definitions you would rather manually put the arguments of `foreign key` and `local key` instead of the auto-incremental id (PK).

Comment: as have tested on Laravel 7, this is correct and will be equivalent to sql query ALTER TABLE `kitchen` ADD UNIQUE `kitchen_restaurant_id_ name_unique`(`restaurant_id`, `name `);

Answer (score 7):

Eloquent's increments() sets the column as an unsigned integer.  With that in mind you have multiple way of achieving your desired composite keys.

You could use either interger() or unsignedInteger() and setting the autoIncrements to true:

```
 $table->integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false);

 $table->unsignedInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false);
 //Returns $this->integer($column, $autoIncrement, true);
```

Then you could tell Eloquent which are your primary keys via primary().

Your Schema::create() should look like this:

```
 Schema::create('kitchen', function($table) {
     $table->integer('id', true, true);
     $table->integer('restaurant_id')->unsigned(); //or $table->integer('restaurant_id', false, true);
     $table->foreign('restaurant_id')
           ->references('id')->on('restaurants')
           ->onDelete('cascade');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->primary(array('id', 'restaurant_id'));
 });
```

Assuming your Restaurant table is using $table->increments('id') this should make 'id' and 'restaurant_id' your primary keys while also matching 'restaurant_id' to the Restaurant table 'id'.

Answer (score 4):

Another option from [Dayle Rees](http://daylerees.com/codebright/schema)

```
Schema::create('example', function($table)
{
    $table->integer('id');
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('email');
    $keys = array('id', 'username', 'email');
    $table->primary($keys);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't make `id` `AUTO INCREMENT`

Comment: Nice solution for non auto increment id's.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've hit something that is not currently possible with Laravel, since `->increments()` already sets `->primary()` , so when you add it yourself you end up with two `PRIMARY` clauses in the resulting SQL.

But you may want to try creating the table with the wrong primary key, dropping it, then recreating it:

```php
Schema::create("kitchen", function($table) 
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('restaurant_id');
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::table('kitchen', function($table)
{
    $table->dropPrimary('kitchen_id_primary');
});

Schema::table('kitchen', function($table)
{
    $table->primary(array('id', 'restaurant_id'));
});
```

Comment: But, I can't make `id` `AUTO_INCREMENT` again, can I ?

Comment: `$table->increments('id');` will make it an autoinc + primary key, but `$table->dropPrimary('kitchen_id_primary');` will only remove the primary key. So the field will remain autoinc. Then `$table->primary(array('id', 'restaurant_id'));` will re-create the composite primary key.

Comment: you can not drop primary if auto inc is set

Comment: @CanGeliş
Looking at laravel's sources reveals the following : 

public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)

So by just passing true you can have it autoincremented

Comment: @Rommy `increments($col)` is just an alias of `unsignedInteger($col, $autoInc)`. So the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
Schema::create("kitchen", function($table) 
{
  $table->integer('id');
  $table->integer('restaurant_id');
  $table->string('name');
}); 
Schema::table('kitchen', function($table)
{
  $table->primary(array('id', 'restaurant_id'));
});
Schema::table('pamenus', function ($table) 
{
    $table->increments('xsl')->change();
});
```

> If you have not installed doctrine/dbal package. Please install
> doctrine/dbal package first. Changing columns for table requires
> doctrine/dbal package. Run this command on the root directory of the framework:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```